# Instruments Exited with code 253 - Appium, iOS, mac, Eclipse

Tags: ios, eclipse, macos, xcode6, appium

Hi I am receiving this error and I am definitely running on device. here are my details. Thanks in advance

am trying to do a simple launch application on a real device to no avail. My settings are as follows: iphone 6, iOS 8.0, Mac OSX 10.9.5, Xcode 6.1, Appium 1.3.1 (I have also tried running from the node appium 1.3.3 (same error)). Appium settings - I have tried running from 127.0.0.1/4723 and 0.0.0.0/4723. any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Have tried numerous troubleshooting tips from online..including clearing the Device console in Xcode...clearing cache using node command. adding permissions...

```
info: [debug] Starting instruments

info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments

info: Launching instruments

info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 3bf6e2888395e77e8d74e3c89140326670afaf3e info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 3bf6e2888395e77e8d74e3c89140326670afaf3e com.safenetinc.mpbasic -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-9280a4dc9be20ec9.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {} info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253

info: [debug] Killall instruments

info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup

info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #1 info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator

Eclipse code: DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "ios");      
    capabilities.setCapability("udid", "3##########");
    capabilities.setCapability("bundleId", "com.ssssss.mptest");
    capabilities.setCapability("ipa", "/Users/user/Desktop/Mptest.ipa");



    try
    {
        System.out.println("before app is launched");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        System.out.println("connected1");
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: I found help in another forum. The issue was with the developer certificate. I had previously registered with apple..under another id..but needed to redo my certificate using my developers id. Then the developer profile had to be recompiled and downloaded again. i removed previous copies from my device and xcode